# Type error when using recursion accumulating lists

Tags: recursion, types, compiler-errors, ocaml, accumulate

A dictionary is a list of pairs. The task is to take a dictionary and return a pair of lists: the keys and values.

I tried to do it iterating (using recursion) over the dictionary and accumulating keys and values in two lists, but I get a type error that baffles me.

**Note: I am *NOT* looking for an alternative solution to the task. I want to understand the error and how to correct it.**

Here is the code:

```
let lists_of_dict dict =
  let rec separate dict keys values =
    match dict with
      [] -> (keys, values)
    | (k, v)::t -> separate t k::keys v::values
                (* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ *)
  in
  separate dict [] []
```

(the underlined part is characters 19-47 of line 5)

Here is the error message:

```
File "lod-problem.ml", line 5, characters 19-47:
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'b * 'c
```

I can't understand why Ocaml deduces that type, and how to make it understand that the expression has type `('a list * 'b list)` (if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`separate t k::keys v::values` parses as `(separate t k) :: (keys v) :: values`, not `separate t (k::keys) (v::values)` as you intended.

So OCaml sees that you build the result using `::` and thus the result is going to be a list (never mind the fact that the arguments for `::` also have the wrong type - the type checker never gets that far), but the expected result is a tuple (because that's what the first case produced). So at that point the type checker errors out.

Comment: Thanks! I should use parens more liberally in the future `:)`